# Django, how do i compare leftovers

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models, warehouse and products.
Subcategories are Hotdog value and
There are two values ​​in the warehouse, sausage and bun, I indicated the quantity to them

I connected them using ManyToMany, now I need to make it show how many pieces there are.

Example.

In the warehouse there is a sausage and a bun
if they are 2 pieces there

then I have a subcategory hot dog should show 2 pieces there

and if there is a sausage in the warehouse of 0 pieces and a bun of 5 pieces

the hotdock should show 0 pieces, because I don’t have sausages

[image]

```
models.py
    class Stock(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        limit = models.IntegerField()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title

    class SubCategory(models.Model):
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        price = models.IntegerField()
        stock = models.ManyToManyField(Stock)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

views.py

```
{% for item in subcategories %}
            <a href="#" class="c-item">
                <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
                <h4>
                    {{ item.price }} сом
                    <span class="badge badge-danger">20 pieces</span>
                </h4>
            </a>
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is far too much ambiguity in your question.

What is the purpose of your "stock" row in the model? What does your Stock model look like?

I don't know if something is lost in translation here, but generally the word "stock" would refer to a quantity, in which case I would use:

```
stock = models.IntegerField()
```

Then i would use some sort of methods (e.g. "add_stock()" and "remove_stock()") which then add or remove a certain quantity.

Comment: Example.

In the warehouse there is a sausage and a bun
if they are 2 pieces there

then I have a subcategory hot dog should show 2 pieces there

and if there is a sausage in the warehouse of 0 pieces and a bun of 5 pieces

the hotdock should show 0 pieces, because I don’t have sausages

Comment: or how can i get value subcategory.stock.title ? and title with limit